# Login Page with session

Tags: php, authentication, session, cart

I am storing data into database,with customer id.The insertion will be done only if the customer is logged in.if the user moves to any other page and comes back to same page the customer id disappears .so i need to include customer id in every page and how do  i do it.the login page must be in last part.

Comment: Can't you simply store the customer id in a session variable when the user logs in? Then you will have access to the customer id whenever you want. Not sure if that solves you issue though. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: how to update the session value of previous page

Comment: @MohanP there is no such thing as "session value of previous page" I think. Because session is a global value.

Answer (score 1):

Once the authentication (ex. login with a mail & password) finishes and successful, you can store the `user id` in the session Global Variable like this: `$_SESSION['user'] = $id`

And as long as the session is alive, you can retrieve this `id` from this Super Variable on any page: `$user_id = $_SESSION['user']`

Make sure to use `session_start()` before using the session global variable. Like:

```
<?php
// index.php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['user'];
```

If you're not using `front controller pattern` then you have to use this function on every page before using `$_SESSION`.

Comment: thank you Jay Wadhwa but error comes as undefined user.

Comment: @MohanP glad I could help. Make sure to accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must start the `session` using `session_start()` in every page at the top. refer from below link.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Thank you sir..I found my solution